# iOS Storyboard: Embedding the root view of a view controller in a new view

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In the Xcode interface builder, you can select a view and embed it a new view using `Editor > Embed In > View`.

I want to do the same to the root view of the view controller, but this is not supported by the 'Embed In' action (only embedding in a controller is suggested, not embedding in a view).

How can I replace the current root view with a new view, and make the old root be a child of the new one?

Comment: Are you trying to do this at run-time? Or just during design? And why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Just during the design. I have actually solved it by doing 'copy' on the old root-view and 'paste' it in the new one...

Comment: But I had to re-connect some outlets and actions.

Comment: Make sure to add `key="view"` if copy and pasting the storyboard source. My subviews didn't show up until I did this.